# Adding [ref] parameter as optional to function behave as mandatory

Tags: powershell

I have a long time working function and now need to add it an **optional [ref] parameter**.
The new function header:

```
function Wait-ForRunningJobs
{
    Param(
        $jobs,
        [int]$jobsLimit,
        [Switch]$SilentlyContinue,
        [switch]$writeOutput,
        [switch]$noTabs,
        [switch]$failOnError,
        [switch]$keepFailedJobs,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [ref]$failedJobs
    )
*
*
*
*
}
```

When I call it this way, everything is fine:

```
Wait-ForRunningJobs -failedJobs ([ref]$failedJobsList) -jobs $jobs -writeOutput -noTabs -keepFailedJobs -SilentlyContinue
```

But my other calls to the functions looks like this

```
Wait-ForRunningJobs $jobs $asyncJobsLimit -writeOutput -SilentlyContinue $shouldIgnoreErrors
```

are failing with this error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'failedJobs'. Reference type is expected in argument.
```

I tried to call the function with the paramaters names, but still getting the same error

```
Wait-ForRunningJobs -jobs $jobs -jobsLimit $asyncJobsLimit -writeOutput $true -SilentlyContinue $true -failOnError $shouldIgnoreErrors
```

Comment: Add a default value.  Parameters without a default are required : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: So, how does it works without passing the $jobsLimit parameter?

Comment: Set a default value of 100.

Comment: @jdweng, parameters are only ever mandatory _if explicitly decorated with `[Parameter(Mandatory)]`_. Please consider deleting your comments - they are a misleading distraction.

Comment: @YirmiOppenhime,  as an aside: This implies that `[Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]` is redundant in your `$failedJobs` parameter declaration and that, conversely, you must use decorate those parameters that you want to be _mandatory_ (required) with `[Parameter(Mandatory)]` (short for `[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]`)

Comment: I tried your “failing” sample in tio.run with Powershell *and* Powershell core but I wasn’t able to reproduce the error - both ran successfully. Could you confirm you’ve tested the code *as posted* to make sure you haven’t minimised away the error by mistake in your sample?

Comment: @mclayton, make the function body empty and invoke with `Wait-ForRunningJobs 1 2  -writeOutput -SilentlyContinue $true`, and you'll see the error in both editions. Yirmi's intent is to pass `$true` _as a value to the `-SilentlyContinue` switch_, but it positionally binds to the `-failedJobs` parameter instead. Placing `:` between `-SilentlyContinue` and its value is a syntactic necessity in this case.

Comment: @mklement0 - ah, yeah - it needs a ```$shouldIgnoreErrors = $true``` before the function call to trigger the reported error. It runs without raising the error if ```$shouldIgnoreErrors``` is undefined, which is what I was trying by cutting &pasting the OP’s code…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order **to pass a *value* to a `[switch]`-typed parameter** (which can only be `$true` or `$false`), you must **separate the parameter name from its value with `:`**

```bash
# Note the ":" between -SilentlyContinue and $shouldIgnoreErrors
Wait-ForRunningJobs $jobs $asyncJobsLimit -writeOutput -SilentlyContinue:$shouldIgnoreErrors
```

Without `:`, `$shouldIgnoreErrors` is considered a *separate*, *unnamed* argument that binds *positionally*, which in the case at hand means binding to the *third* positional parameter,<sup>[1]</sup> which happens to be the `[ref]`-typed `-failedJobs` parameter (which therefore fails, because only `[ref]` instances can be passed to `[ref]`-typed parameters).

Note that while you're free to *always* use `:` to separate a parameter name from its value, doing so is rare, and it is only *syntactically necessary* in the case of `[switch]` parameters, which are the only type of parameter in PowerShell that *optionally* accepts a value in a *named* argument, so that `:` is required to disambiguate such an optional value from a subsequent *positional* argument (that binds to a *different* parameter).

---

<sup>[1] Note that non-`[switch]` parameter declarations are positional *by default*, based on their declaration order.

You can *opt-out* of this by setting with by decorating your `param(…)` block `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute and setting its `PositionalBinding` property of the  to `$false` (e.g., `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`), which makes all parameters non-positional by default.

You may then use *selective opt-in* to positional binding by decorating individual parameters with a `[Parameter()]` attribute and setting the latter's `Position` property to a position number, which determines the position relative to the numbers of other parameters declared this way (`0` is by convention used to designate the *first* positional parameter).

See the conceptual [about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute) and [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters) help topics.</sup>